# Rendering field groups (not individual fields)

Tags: entities, theming

I am using [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) to group my fields. Purpose of this is to have better control when rendering them inside the node.tpl.php file. Specifically, I want to designate in the node.tpl.php where in the html document I want specific groups of fields rendered, while sorting fields and designating what fields belong to what group inside the UI.

Do you think Field Group is a good way of achieving this? If grouping fields using Field Group, how do you then render that group in the template file?

Edit: I am steering towards template solutions, avoiding the likes of Panels and DS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using `hide()` on content elements I wanted place independently before `print render`ing the rest of content. As I have learned the way drupal renders/prints makes this very easy. Example:

```
<?php hide($content['product:title']); ?>
<div>
  <?php print render($content); ?> <!-- $content['product:title'] is not output -->
</div>
<div>
  <?php print render($content['product:field_image']); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 it's easy to render group or individual field of groups in template file for theme

If want to render full  group with subgroup then

`print render($content['group_cruiseline_ships'];`

If want to render only subgroup then

`print render($content['group_shop']['product'];`

If want to render only specific field of subgroup or group then

`print render($content['group_shop']['product']['field_keyboard'];`

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use field groups' div type with display suite  to stack my fields for better CSS control. No need to go into template files.

Here you can see how I have wrapped the fields in field groups with divs
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s272/sh/976bd05c-8b35-41d3-aad1-107ede26de09/a0d68b931e6093b9ea27a1cd5d952420

Here is the html-code:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s272/sh/0e695fad-6a47-4249-9110-2c79a1999c73/aa7f981b606e977a38b70d61cf94dd6c

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I am steering towards template function solutions.